# Linking to a page with a unique id

Tags: php, html

This might be a very simple one, but I could not find a good answer for my question.

I will have several users in my webpage, and I will not have a specific .html/.php page for each one. So what I want is: a link like this one:

```
users.php/#id=test_user1
```

or this one

```
users.php/?id=test_user1
```

opens users.php and sets

```
<?php
$_SESSION['user_name']='test_user1';
?>
```

or directs me to another page where I do

```
<?php
$_SESSION['user_name']='test_user1';
echo "<script>window.location = 'users.php'</script>"
?>
```

I keep seeing similar uses in several webpages but I haven't figured out how it is done.

Comment: It's very clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Do you mean to say `users.php/?id=test_user1`?

Comment: that is also ok. any link ending with id=test_user1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to use `users.php/?id=test_user1` since all you need to do is:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_GET['id'];
?>
```

This takes whatever the query string `id` is set to and sets it as `$_SESSION['user_name']`.

Answer (score 0):

encode varialbes in url lik.. using get method

users.php?id=user_id

then ask your php to gather data from database or whatever ...
and show them there profile..